# nginx Permission denied 403

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, permissions

I'm having a tough time getting an `Orange Pi` (`Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS`) to serve static websites on `nginx`.  I get the following error:

```
2022/12/17 23:05:41 [error] 5206#5206: *4 "/home/user3/sites/vhost1/index.html" is forbidden (13: Permission denied), client: 192.168.1.4, server: vhost1.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "pt.local:8080"
2022/12/17 23:05:41 [error] 5234#5234: *5 open() "/home/user3/sites/vhost1/favicon.ico" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 192.168.1.4, server: vhost1.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "pt.lo
cal:8080", referrer: "http://pt.local:8080/"
```

Permissions on that `vhost` are 755, and ownership is to :.  The **wwwuser** is deliberately made to serve sites using nginx.

`SELINUX=disabled`

How can I make these sites serve properly?

Comment: The user running Nginx needs access to **every** directory in the path, not just `vhost1`.

Comment: @RichardSmith Which path?  The `www` site path?

Comment: @RichardSmith Ya I'm still getting 403's on that.  `rwxr-x--- 1 myself wwwgroup  610 Dec 19 10:54  index.html`

Comment: Every directory needs to be accessible, including: `home`, `user3`, and `sites`.

Comment: @RichardSmith OK, every single directory in / is `root:root` so that means `nginx` can't be used.

Comment: Not at all. There is the owner, the group, and others. The root directories probably give others `r-x` access, which allows Nginx to descend to the next level. It's probably `user3` that needs checking.

Comment: @RichardSmith Bingo.  That was it.  `user3` had `750`.  I know it's odd to hold `www` inside my user home directory, but it's convenient.  `Ubuntu` seems historically convoluted with respect to setting up permissions, and `nginx` is known for this.  In any case I've moved onto a `Raspberry Pi 4`, which was almost an instant setup. Cheers